# How to capture API requests before they are routed through VPN?

Tags: macos, wireshark

When my computer is connected to VPN, the only traffic I see in Wireshark is the VPN ESP packets.

Is it possible to capture traffic before it is routed through VPN such as API requests?

Comment: please add operating system and any other tag you might deem useful.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... had to capture packets on the `ipsec0` interface.